# Vapor Barrier Under Insulation on Attic Floor

Tags: insulation, vapor-barrier

My brother tore out the mdf tile ceiling of his cottage and nailed down ~1x6 pallet wood on top of the ceiling joists in the attic. There are large gaps in the boards. On top of the boards, he rolled some R19 for insulation. This is a summer home only.

His place gets very hot. I am going to recommend he put up radiant barrier in the rafters, but would there be any benefit to rolling up the insulation temporarily and putting a vapor barrier underneath, on top of the pallet wood?

Comment: Why are you suggesting the vapor barrier?

Comment: Is there insulation below the boards in the joists if so you do not want a double barrier.

Comment: @IronEagle I figured free airflow between the sides might hurt their insulating efforts. Maybe not the case with AC below and heat above?

Comment: @Ed there is nothing below between the joists. Insulation only sits on top of them